# Javascript str.replace with dollar sign not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Sample string being replaced:**

```
https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjss/bs.serving-sys.com/52023/7720220/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=1234567890&PluID=0&w=300&h=600&ord=[timestamp]&ucm=true&ncu=$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$&adsafe_preview=${IS_PREVIEW}`
```

**Replacements I'm trying to make:**

```
$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$  --> $$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$
[timestamp]         --> ${CACHEBUSTER}
```

**Desired output:**

```
https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjss/bs.serving-sys.com/52023/7720220/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=1234567890&PluID=0&w=300&h=600&ord=${CACHEBUSTER}&ucm=true&ncu=$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$&adsafe_preview=${IS_PREVIEW}
```

---

**Code I've tried:**

*Code:*

```
var v = $("textarea#creative-content").val();
v = v.replace(/\$\$\{CLICK\_URL\_ENC\}\$/g, "$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$");
v = v.replace("[timestamp]","${CACHEBUSTER}");
console.log(v);
```

*Output:*

- Changed `[timestamp]` to `${CACHEBUSTER}`: **Yes**
- Changed `$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$` to `$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$`: **No**

*Code:*

```
var v = $("textarea#creative-content").val();
v = v.replace("$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$", "$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$");
v = v.replace("[timestamp]","${CACHEBUSTER}");
console.log(v);
```

*Output:*

- Changed `[timestamp]` to `${CACHEBUSTER}`: **Yes**
- Changed `$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$` to `$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$`: **No**

*Code:*

```
var v = $("textarea#creative-content").val();
v = v.replace("\$\${CLICK_URL_ENC}\$", "\$\$\${CLICK_URL_ENC}\$\$");
v = v.replace("[timestamp]","${CACHEBUSTER}");
console.log(v);
```

*Output:*

- Changed `[timestamp]` to `${CACHEBUSTER}`: **Yes**
- Changed `$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$` to `$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$`: **No**

---

How can I make the changes I'm looking for using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: You [need to escape `$`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) in the replacement string in various ways as it's a special char.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I have tried `v = v.replace("\$\${CLICK_URL_ENC}\$", "\$\$\${CLICK_URL_ENC}\$\$");` with no luck...

Comment: Read the docs - you don't escape it with a \.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan : `replace("$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$", "$$$$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$$$")`

Comment: @Hacketo thank you... Post as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @BenPearlKahan feel free to accept answer bellow, I just commented. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In replacements $ is a special char used when you capture a group, so it needs to be escaped...with $ signs, which gives us something not readable, like this:

```
'$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$'.replace(/\$\${CLICK_URL_ENC}\$/g, '$$$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$$');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `escape` the dollar signs. This is done by typing two in a row. You want to have 3 dollar signs in the beginning, which means you have to have 6 dollar signs in the replace string:

```
v.replace("$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$", "$$$$$${CLICK_URL_ENC}$$$$");
```